# error:HTTP Status 404 - There is no Action mapped for namespace / and action name FileUpExample

Tags: struts2, interceptor

I am trying to do a upload file example using struts2 .I have used interceptors .When I am trying to run the following code I am getting the above 404 error showing.."There is no Action mapped for namespace / and action name FileUpExample"

My inex.jsp is:

```html
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<%@ taglib uri="/struts-tags" prefix="s" %>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<center>
<s:form action="FileUpExample" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<s:file name="file" label="Choose File" size="40"/>
<s:submit value="Upload" name="Submit"/>
</s:form>

</center>

</body>
</html>
```

uploadsuccess.jsp

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>DeleteEx</display-name>
  
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
 
  <filter>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
  </filter>
  
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
  
</web-app>
```

struts.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
   "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
   "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">
   
  <struts>
    <constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />
    <package name="default" extends="struts-default">
     <action name="FileUpExample" class="b.FileUpExampleAction">
      <interceptor-ref name="fileUpload">
            <param name="maximumSize">10485760</param>
         <param name="allowedTypes">text/plain,image/jpeg,image/gif, image/png,image/pjpeg </param>
         </interceptor-ref>
         <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack">
         </interceptor-ref>
         <result name="success">uploadsuccess.jsp</result>
     </action> 
       
        </package>
  </struts>
```

action class

package b;
import java.io.File;

import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;

public class FileUpExampleAction extends ActionSupport{

```
/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private File file;
private String fileContentType;
private String fileFileName;
public File getFile() {
    return file;
}
public void setFile(File file) {
    this.file = file;
}
public String getFileContentType() {
    return fileContentType;
}
public void setFileContentType(String fileContentType) {
    this.fileContentType = fileContentType;
}
public String getFileFileName() {
    return fileFileName;
}
public void setFileFileName(String fileFileName) {
    this.fileFileName = fileFileName;
}

 public String execute()
 {
     /*path where uploaded file will be stored*/
        String targetpath="C:\test";
        System.out.println("path where uploaded file will be stored" +targetpath);
        File fileToCreate= new File(targetpath, this.fileFileName);
        try{
                FileUtils.copyFile(this.file,fileToCreate);
            }
     catch(Exception e){
         e.printStackTrace();
     }
    return SUCCESS;


 }
```

}

I would be obliged if someone gives the idea where I am going wrong.

The stacktrace:

```html
Jan 27, 2015 5:41:41 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:/Program Files/Java/jre7/bin/client;C:/Program Files/Java/jre7/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jre7/lib/i386;C:\orant\bin;c:\perl\site\bin;c:\perl\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\system32\wbem;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\TortoiseSVNSCC\bin;C:\apache-maven-3.0.3\bin;...;c:\program files\ibm\gsk8\lib;D:\instantclient;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_13\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jre6;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\SvnStat-1.0;C:\Program Files\Subversion\bin;F:\svnreport\apache-ant-1.8.2\bin;F:\svnreport\apache-ant-1.8.2\lib;C:\orant\jdk\bin;C:\Program Files\Subversion\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\WINDOWS\system32\;;F:\TestWork\eclipse;;.
Jan 27, 2015 5:41:41 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:FileUploadExample' did not find a matching property.
Jan 27, 2015 5:41:41 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8081"]
Jan 27, 2015 5:41:41 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Jan 27, 2015 5:41:41 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 757 ms
Jan 27, 2015 5:41:41 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Jan 27, 2015 5:41:41 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.47
Jan 27, 2015 5:41:42 PM org.apache.catalina.util.SessionIdGenerator createSecureRandom
INFO: Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took [250] milliseconds.
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
Jan 27, 2015 5:41:45 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8081"]
Jan 27, 2015 5:41:45 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Jan 27, 2015 5:41:45 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 3315 ms
Jan 27, 2015 5:41:48 PM org.apache.jasper.compiler.TldLocationsCache tldScanJar
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
```

This is showing in the browser:

```html
HTTP Status 404 - There is no Action mapped for namespace / and action name FileUpExample.

type Status report

message There is no Action mapped for namespace / and action name FileUpExample.

description The requested resource is not available.
Apache Tomcat/7.0.47
```

thats it nothing else

Comment: What is the context?

Comment: Actually i am not able to figure out why error 404 is occuring as I have mapped the pages in struts.xml.do any more mapping is required?or do anywhere I need to edit?

Comment: I have posted the stacktrace above.

Comment: It's not a stacktrace, I want to see the error with *"There is no Action mapped for namespace / and action name FileUpExample"*.

Comment: this is what showing in the browser